# Find unicode ID for comined symbols

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I try to understand how Unicode works in representing specific combinations of symbols.
For instance, if I combine the following three Devengari (hindi) symbols:

> न + ◌् ([diacritical combination symbol](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/)) + न

I should get the following [one](https://www.sannyas.wiki/index.php?title=Devanagari_Ligatures) [(second link here)](http://www.aa.tufs.ac.jp/%7Ekmach/gicas/ASTI/conj_e.htm):

> न्न

Now, for the first three symbols I was able to find the corresponding [Unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/) symbols using `Character Map` in Windows and I got:

> न --> UTF-16 Encoding: 0x0928
>
> ◌् --> UTF-16 Encoding: 0x094D

Or, equivalent, in Unicode xml representation:

> न --> "&#2344";
>
> ◌् --> "&#2381";

Now, despite my efforts to find the combinations of those three I didn't
succeed, anyhow, this symbol `न्न` must have a Unicode representation, right?

Thanks.

Comment: this https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ is a good primer on Unicode

Answer (score 3):

Unicode is about character "code". Not about glyphs (so figures).

Unicode codepoint have different interpretation. Usually a printable character, or a combining  character (which will modify the previous characters).

In addition, fonts could merge also other characters (not only with combining unicode code point). On Latin scripts (block letters) this is very seldom, but in Indian language, it is the rule. But Indian languages have also different rules on how to combine or merge characters. You may define it with the fonts, with language modifier (e.g. in HTML), or/and with `zero width non-joiner` and `zero width joiner`. These marks the intent: do you want to have two character show as independent (so noo-joiner), or do you want them to show as combined (also if fonts will prefer such combination as disjoint).

You may need to read [Unicode: Official Scripts of India](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/ch12.pdf) and successive chapter. You get much more inside on how Indian scripts works with unicode, and you get the huge exceptions and rules (Unicode is also for older version of actual languages).

Note: There is a `DEVANAGARI LETTER NNNA` ऩ, and `DEVANAGARI LETTER NNA`ण. I do not know Indian languages, but should be NNA be like your character? (But they seems totally different).

But as you see on my linked document (from Unicode), you see that there are many rules and exceptions (and recommendation) on how to mix codepoints. It is not a easy language for Unicode, and more complex for font designers.

Comment: I added the two last paragraphs about possible merged characters (but they look different).

Answer (score 2):

Your symbol is a triple combination (Python used for ordinals and naming):

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s='न्न'
>>> len(s)
3
>>> for c in s: print(f'{c}   U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
... 
न   U+0928 DEVANAGARI LETTER NA
्   U+094D DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
न   U+0928 DEVANAGARI LETTER NA
```

There is no single Unicode character for its glyph.  Normalizing combines code points if possible:

```
>>> len(ud.normalize('NFC',s))
3
```

Comment: I'm not sure about last recommendation: Unicode (by design) prefers decomposing. Vimara is not an accent or a modifier in a strict sense. It just remove the implicit vocal. BTW Indian languages merge various letters (like we do in Latin cursive: on Latin we never want such combinations on strings (just on display), merging it is not always the good way to read text. BTW I think the resulting glyph depend on language. [BTW I didn't find it, but often Unicode have combinations outside `NFC` (and they should only be used by on very restricted linguistic cases).

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi, virama **is** a Nonspacing_Mark/Combining_Mark, same as accents. Check properties.

Comment: @daxim: Yeah, for the Unicode encoding, but semantically is very different. For this reason we have ZWJ and ZWNJ (possibly the most used words in Unicode standard), In print latin you mau just use ZWNJ for very specific usues. It is also the reasons there are many combinations which should be avoided in Unicode (e.g. see Devanagari chapter). On Latin language you may remove accent and text is still readable. Vimara has effect also on following character. It describe the vocals (or lack of it) between the two consonants.

Answer (score -1):

Let's first define some terms accurately.

Unicode makes a distinction between characters and graphemes (or grapheme clusters). You're talking about symbols, but you actually mean characters. Symbol is just a property of a character:

```
U+0928 ‹न› \N{DEVANAGARI LETTER NA} Other_Letter
U+25CC ‹◌› \N{DOTTED CIRCLE} Other_Symbol
U+094D ‹◌्› \N{DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA} Combining_Mark
```

Each character has an numeric id (four or five hex digits) which is called codepoint.

---

All of the previous is low-level detail which does not need to concern end-users or programmers dealing with text, it should be relevant only for a few programmers implementing Unicode for a programming language. (Unfortunately, most software – including programming languages – is broken, badly designed or badly implemented, so the abstraction leaks.) One the Unicode level, न्न consists of two graphemes:

```
› perl -Mutf8 -E 'say scalar split /\b{g}/, "न्न"'
2
› perl6 -e '"न्न".chars.say'
2
› node -e 'console.log((new(require("grapheme-splitter"))).countGraphemes("न्न"))'
2
```

(The Python answer showing 3 is incorrect.)

You can still see it's two graphemes when marking text, or deleting text starting from the right-hand side with the <kbd>⌫</kbd> Backspace key:

[image]

---

न्न renders as single glyph because it is a ligature. Many scripts are weird like that, not only Devanagari. [This topic has little to do with Unicode, though, this is the task of the font renderer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900880/46395) Therefore, your question finding an id in Unicode for the glyph does not make sense – it only has a single id inside the font file. For example, in the font family "Noto Sans Devanagari UI", the glyph can be found by its id `nanadeva`.

Comment: Python `len` count the codepoint, which it is often the most important part for programmer (eg. to iterate to one string). Just one should know what `len`/size/. etc are describing. It is really not a bug or bad implementation. And in Indian languages, the same codepoints could be printed with different number of graphemes (old write tend to use less graphemes, but also different regions use different convention). Only getting data back from font rendering can give the right length in graphemes. BTW there is an Unicode annex also for that (cursor position).

Comment: You're pretty much wrong with sentences 1,2,3,5 of what you just wrote. One can't iterate or measure by codepoints and expect it to do something sane or useful; in Python, an appropriate library must be used. Length of graphemes can be measured algorithmically without font rendering, the code above proves it. Please read annex 29, it backs up what I said.

Comment: We have a different interpretation. Try to implement Unicode algorithms with grapheme as base unit, and you will see why sometime it is useful to use codepoint as unit. I read the Unicode Standard, and it seems to confirm what I said about lengths. Often you need extra information (outside Unicode main database). Before saying Python people (the implementer) are stupid and know nothing about Unicode, you should be much much more careful).

Comment: I never said "stupid", you're putting words into my mouth. Go take a hike.

Comment: "is broken, badly designed or badly implemented, so the abstraction leaks.". If this is not saying "stupid" to such people... You should word your opinions more carefully, not to seems too much arrogant. I just wrote why it make sense to use Python definition (in a lot of fields), not that that is the only (or the best) solution. Counting graphemes is useful on display, not on network, not on reserving space on memory, nor to implement the various Unicode algorithms.

Comment: Re: "The Python answer showing 3 is incorrect." The Python code is counting code points not graphemes.  There are 3 code points.  The Python 3rd party library `regex` can count graphemes and gets the same 2 result.  The result seems incorrect to me as a grapheme is usually considered a "perceived character" and न्न looks like a single perceived character to me, but I'm no expert at that script. My Hindi-expert friend says it is a single character :)

Comment: *> counting code points not graphemes* That's the point. It's doing the wrong thing without using a library. I don't know how much more clear I can make that. Don't pretend it's normal and right just because a lot of software is badly implemented like that.

Comment: I'm already repeating myself: "One can't iterate or measure by codepoints and expect it to do something sane or useful" – Now kindly take off, you're not contributing anything useful to the comments.